# CSS3 elements color in sublime

Tags: sublimetext2

I have been using sublime for about half and year and now i want to make some modifies to it. I installed few packages and rest of stuff but i have a kind of problem.

Using theme Monokai ( and also in other tested themes ), i can't give the right color to attributes like "-webkit-box-shadow" and other css3 elements. I mean, i would like to have the right color also for vendor prefixes and new css3 elements.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this `<dict>` entry to your `.tmTheme` file to have the right colors for all (also unknown) css property names:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>CSS property name</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>meta.property-name.css</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string>italic</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#66D9EF</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a plugin that solves my problem https://github.com/i-akhmadullin/Sublime-CSS . Closed !